# How to avoid calling Slack webhook during integration tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, integration-testing, slack-api

Our `Spring-Boot` application is calling a `Slack` webhook in order to publish some messages to a Slack channel:

```
new RestTemplate().postForObject(slackChannel, new HttpEntity(...), String.class);
```

Our challenge is how **not** to call `Slack` during the testing phases of the app.

During the **unit test** phase, we are injecting and mocking the Slack service so nothing is sent to Slack and all is OK.

The problem is during the **integration tests** when the system works as a whole and we surely don't want messages to be actually sent to Slack.

One option was to inject a false URL of the webhook, but then we get a

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden

We can surely wrap the calling code with `Try + Catch` but that seems awkward.

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution we found was this:

1. We are calling the `sendToSlack` method in an Async way
2. We are using a false URL as the webhook URL (e.g. http://noslack.com)

This way, when running the integration tests the app will try & fail to send a message to Slack, but since it will run in a different thread, it will not affect the app itself.

This is not a 100% perfect solution, as the log of the app now contains errors about the slack calls (when running in tests/dev phases)